# Create a Firefox plugin that interacts with our java application

Tags: java, firefox-addon

I have a java application that i made which stores the contacts to a web server and connects through apis to import send mail and so on.

I was thinking if there was any easy way to call my classes from a firefox plugin and send email etc.

I dont want to go very deep if that is alot of trouble i currently know Java, C, JavaScript, PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I never used it, but there's information on MDN on calling java code from a firefox-addon.

See it here : [Java in Firefox Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Java_in_Firefox_Extensions)